# Overfull \hbox ( too wide)

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have a lot (27) tables of data like this and I want them to be centered, but they aren't and I'm getting this warning on each of them.. HELP!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,wrapfig,color,lastpage}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.75in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1in}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[round, semicolon]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\chemsetup{
    modules = all,
    formula = mhchem
}

\definecolor{Red}{rgb}{0.8,0.2,0.2}
\definecolor{Blue}{rgb}{0.2,0.2,0.8}

\sloppy
\textwidth=6.5in \textheight 9in \oddsidemargin=0in \topmargin=-0.5in

\cfoot{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\scriptsize
    \centering
    \caption{Ne-Kls Viscosity Data Ne75}
    \medskip
    \label{Ne$_{75}$Kls$_{25}$+XF Viscosity Data}
    %\begin{adjustbox}{angle=90} 
    \begin{tabular}{|c|cccccccccccc|}

        \hline
        \hline

            Sample & Wt. \% F & Mol \% F & Segment & Method & $T$ ($^{\circ}C$) & $T$ (K) & log$\eta$ & A & B & C & T$^{12}$ & m   \\
        \hline 
        \hline
     Ne$_{100}$+0F & 0.00$\pm$0.00 & 0.00 & 9a  & PP & 800 & 1073 & 12.07 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
                 & 0.00$\pm$0.00 & 0.00 & 7b  & PP & 828 & 1101 & 11.04 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
                & 0.00$\pm$0.00 & 0.00 & 8c  & PP & 842 & 1115 & 10.79 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
                 & 0.00$\pm$0.00 & 0.00 & 5  & PP & 856 & 1129 & 10.24 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 &  41.22\\
                & 0.00$\pm$0.00 & 0.00 & 6  & PP & 870 & 1143 & 9.95 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
                & 0.00$\pm$0.00 & 0.00 & 4  & PP & 885 & 1158 & 9.50 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
                 & 0.00$\pm$0.00 & 0.00 & 3b  & CC & 1538 & 1811 & 1.70 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
                & 0.00$\pm$0.00 & 0.00 & 5b  & CC & 1548 & 1821 & 1.65 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
                 & 0.00$\pm$0.00 & 0.00 & 2b  & CC & 1557 & 1830 & 1.60 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
                & 0.00$\pm$0.00 & 0.00 & 1b  & CC & 1572 & 1846 & 1.53 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
                & 0.00$\pm$0.00 & 0.00 & 4b  & CC & 1588 & 1861 & 1.45 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\

     \hline 
    Ne$_{100}$+2F & 0.93$\pm$0.10 & 3.35 & 9  & PP & 821 & 1094 & 10.21 & -4.31 & 7486.03 & 582.01 & 1024 & 39.24\\
                    & 0.93$\pm$0.10 & 3.35 & 4  & PP & 849 & 1122 & 9.67 & -4.31 & 7486.03 & 582.01 & 1024 & 39.24\\
                    & 0.93$\pm$0.10 & 3.35 & 17-18  & CC & 1502 & 1775 & 1.98 & -4.31 & 7486.03 & 582.01 & 1024 & 39.24\\
                    & 0.93$\pm$0.10 & 3.35 & 13-14-15  & CC & 1550 & 1823 & 1.71 & -4.31 & 7486.03 & 582.01 & 1024 & 39.24\\
                    & 0.93$\pm$0.10 & 3.35 & 36-38-39  & CC & 1585 & 1859 & 1.54 & -4.31 & 7486.03 & 582.01 & 1024 & 39.24\\
                    & 0.93$\pm$0.10 & 3.35 & 9-10-11  & CC & 1589 & 1861 & 1.53 & -4.31 & 7486.03 & 582.01 & 1024 & 39.24\\


     \hline
    Ne$_{100}$+4F & 2.42$\pm$0.07 & 8.39 & n.d.  & PP & 679 & 952 & 10.72 & -4.31 & 8395.10 & 393.24 & 908 & 28.81\\
                  & 2.42$\pm$0.07 & 8.39 & n.d.  & PP & 712 & 985 & 9.87 & -4.31 & 8395.10 & 393.24 & 908 & 28.81\\
                  & 2.42$\pm$0.07 & 8.39 & n.d.  & CC & 1513 & 1786 & 1.74 & -4.31 & 8395.10 & 393.24 & 908 & 28.81\\
                  & 2.42$\pm$0.07 & 8.39 & n.d.  & CC & 1561 & 1834 & 1.52 & -4.31 & 8395.10 & 393.24 & 908 & 28.81\\
                  & 2.42$\pm$0.07 & 8.39 & n.d.  & CC & 1585 & 1858 & 1.41 & -4.31 & 8395.10 & 393.24 & 908 & 28.81\\
                  & 2.42$\pm$0.07 & 8.39 & n.d.  & CC & 1589 & 1862 & 1.39 & -4.31 & 8395.10 & 393.24 & 908 & 28.81\\
     \hline
     Ne$_{100}$+6F & 3.62$\pm$0.07 & 12.03 & n.d.  & PP & 596 & 869 & 11.11 & -4.31 & 8526.37 & 324.43 & 832 & 27.57\\
                   & 3.62$\pm$0.07 & 12.03 & n.d.  & PP & 622 & 895 & 10.67 & -4.31 & 8526.37 & 324.43 & 832 & 27.57\\
                   & 3.62$\pm$0.07 & 12.03 & 3  & PP & 651 & 924 & 10.03 & -4.31 & 8526.37 & 324.43 & 832 & 27.57\\
                   & 3.62$\pm$0.07 & 12.03 & n.d.  & PP & 660 & 933 & 9.85 & -4.31 & 8526.37 & 324.43 & 832 & 27.57\\
                   & 3.62$\pm$0.07 & 12.03 & n.d.  & CC & 1514 & 1787 & 1.51 & -4.31 & 8526.37 & 324.43 & 832 & 27.57\\
                   & 3.62$\pm$0.07 & 12.03 & n.d.  & CC & 1558 & 1831 & 1.32 & -4.31 & 8526.37 & 324.43 & 832 & 27.57\\
                   & 3.62$\pm$0.07 & 12.03 & n.d.  & CC & 1581 & 1854 & 1.23 & -4.31 & 8526.37 & 324.43 & 832 & 27.57\\
                   & 3.62$\pm$0.07 & 12.03 & n.d.  & CC & 1582 & 1855 & 1.22 & -4.31 & 8526.37 & 324.43 & 832 & 27.57\\

        \hline
    \end{tabular}
%   \end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Remove the line `\textwidth=6.5in \textheight 9in \oddsidemargin=0in \topmargin=-0.5in`

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the line

```
\textwidth=6.5in \textheight 9in \oddsidemargin=0in \topmargin=-0.5in
```

the table is centred between the given margins. You load a lot of packages, but does not load [geometry](https://ctan.org/pkg/geometry), which will help you to set proper margins in a much easier way, see *example 2*.

However, I suggest that you load [booktabs](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs), [array](https://ctan.org/pkg/array) and [dcolumn](https://ctan.org/pkg/dcolumn) and set your tabular without vertical lines, but with better spacing. Using `D`-columns from [dcolumn](https://ctan.org/pkg/dcolumn), you are able to align your figure columns at the decimal separator. In my example you will see that I separate the second column and input the `\pm` though by removing the space between the columns and replace it with the `\pm` sign. See [the array manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/array.pdf) for further explanation. In the new example 1B, I have set the second row utilising a special feature in the [dcolumn](https://ctan.org/pkg/dcolumn) package, which centres the second column around the plus/minus sign. *Example 1B* is the new MWE, and my recommended solution.:

**Example 1 – booktabs rules and D-columns**

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=0.625in, right=0.625in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, booktabs, dcolumn}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}

%\textwidth=6.5in \textheight 9in \oddsidemargin=0in \topmargin=-0.5in

\cfoot{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\footnotesize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.3em}
    \centering
    \caption{Ne-Kls Viscosity Data Ne75}
    \medskip
    \label{Ne$_{75}$Kls$_{25}$+XF Viscosity Data}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l
                    r@{$\,\pm\,$}l
                    D{.}{.}{3.2}cc
                    D{.}{.}{5.0}
                    D{.}{.}{4.0}
                    D{.}{.}{2.2}
                    D{.}{.}{-1.2}
                    D{.}{.}{4.2}
                    D{.}{.}{3.2}
                    D{.}{.}{4.0}
                    D{.}{.}{2.2}
                    @{}}

\toprule
Sample &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Wt. \% F} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Mol \% F} &
Segment &
Method &
T (^{\circ}C) &
$T (K)$ &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{log$\eta$} &
A & B & C & 
T^{12} & m   \\
\midrule
Ne$_{100}$+0F & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 9a  & PP & 800 & 1073 & 12.07 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
              & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 7b  & PP & 828 & 1101 & 11.04 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
              & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 8c  & PP & 842 & 1115 & 10.79 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
              & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 5  & PP & 856 & 1129 & 10.24 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 &  41.22\\
              & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 6  & PP & 870 & 1143 & 9.95 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
              & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 4  & PP & 885 & 1158 & 9.50 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
              & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 3b  & CC & 1538 & 1811 & 1.70 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
              & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 5b  & CC & 1548 & 1821 & 1.65 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
              & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 2b  & CC & 1557 & 1830 & 1.60 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
              & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 1b  & CC & 1572 & 1846 & 1.53 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
              & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 4b  & CC & 1588 & 1861 & 1.45 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
\midrule

Ne$_{100}$+2F & 0.93 & 0.10 & 3.35 & 9  & PP & 821 & 1094 & 10.21 & -4.31 & 7486.03 & 582.01 & 1024 & 39.24\\
              & 0.93 & 0.10 & 3.35 & 4  & PP & 849 & 1122 & 9.67 & -4.31 & 7486.03 & 582.01 & 1024 & 39.24\\
              & 0.93 & 0.10 & 3.35 & 17-18  & CC & 1502 & 1775 & 1.98 & -4.31 & 7486.03 & 582.01 & 1024 & 39.24\\
              & 0.93 & 0.10 & 3.35 & 13-14-15  & CC & 1550 & 1823 & 1.71 & -4.31 & 7486.03 & 582.01 & 1024 & 39.24\\
              & 0.93 & 0.10 & 3.35 & 36-38-39  & CC & 1585 & 1859 & 1.54 & -4.31 & 7486.03 & 582.01 & 1024 & 39.24\\
              & 0.93 & 0.10 & 3.35 & 9-10-11  & CC & 1589 & 1861 & 1.53 & -4.31 & 7486.03 & 582.01 & 1024 & 39.24\\
\midrule
Ne$_{100}$+4F & 2.42 & 0.07 & 8.39 & n.d.  & PP & 679 & 952 & 10.72 & -4.31 & 8395.10 & 393.24 & 908 & 28.81\\
              & 2.42 & 0.07 & 8.39 & n.d.  & PP & 712 & 985 & 9.87 & -4.31 & 8395.10 & 393.24 & 908 & 28.81\\
              & 2.42 & 0.07 & 8.39 & n.d.  & CC & 1513 & 1786 & 1.74 & -4.31 & 8395.10 & 393.24 & 908 & 28.81\\
              & 2.42 & 0.07 & 8.39 & n.d.  & CC & 1561 & 1834 & 1.52 & -4.31 & 8395.10 & 393.24 & 908 & 28.81\\
              & 2.42 & 0.07 & 8.39 & n.d.  & CC & 1585 & 1858 & 1.41 & -4.31 & 8395.10 & 393.24 & 908 & 28.81\\
              & 2.42 & 0.07 & 8.39 & n.d.  & CC & 1589 & 1862 & 1.39 & -4.31 & 8395.10 & 393.24 & 908 & 28.81\\
\midrule
Ne$_{100}$+6F & 3.62 & 0.07 & 12.03 & n.d.  & PP & 596 & 869 & 11.11 & -4.31 & 8526.37 & 324.43 & 832 & 27.57\\
              & 3.62 & 0.07 & 12.03 & n.d.  & PP & 622 & 895 & 10.67 & -4.31 & 8526.37 & 324.43 & 832 & 27.57\\
              & 3.62 & 0.07 & 12.03 & 3  & PP & 651 & 924 & 10.03 & -4.31 & 8526.37 & 324.43 & 832 & 27.57\\
              & 3.62 & 0.07 & 12.03 & n.d.  & PP & 660 & 933 & 9.85 & -4.31 & 8526.37 & 324.43 & 832 & 27.57\\
              & 3.62 & 0.07 & 12.03 & n.d.  & CC & 1514 & 1787 & 1.51 & -4.31 & 8526.37 & 324.43 & 832 & 27.57\\
              & 3.62 & 0.07 & 12.03 & n.d.  & CC & 1558 & 1831 & 1.32 & -4.31 & 8526.37 & 324.43 & 832 & 27.57\\
               & 3.62 & 0.07 & 12.03 & n.d.  & CC & 1581 & 1854 & 1.23 & -4.31 & 8526.37 & 324.43 & 832 & 27.57\\
               & 3.62 & 0.07 & 12.03 & n.d.  & CC & 1582 & 1855 & 1.22 & -4.31 & 8526.37 & 324.43 & 832 & 27.57\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Example 1B – special D-column**

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=0.625in, right=0.625in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, booktabs, dcolumn, array}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}

%\textwidth=6.5in \textheight 9in \oddsidemargin=0in \topmargin=-0.5in

\cfoot{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.3em}
\footnotesize
\centering
\medskip
\caption{$Ne_{75}Kls_{25}+XF$ Viscosity Data%
               \label{Ne-Kls Viscosity Data Ne75-2}%
               }
\begin{tabular}{@{}
                >{$}l<{$}
                D{+}{\,\pm\,}{3,3}
                D{.}{.}{3.2}
                cc
                D{.}{.}{5.0}
                D{.}{.}{4.0}
                D{.}{.}{2.2}
                D{.}{.}{-1.2}
                D{.}{.}{4.2}
                D{.}{.}{3.2}
                D{.}{.}{4.0}
                D{.}{.}{2.2}
                @{}}

\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{Sample} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$Wt. \% F$} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$Mol \% F$} &
Segment &
Method &
T (^{\circ}C) &
T (K) &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{log$\eta$} &
A & B & C & 
T^{12} &
m  \\
\midrule
Ne_{100}+0F 
           & 0.00+0.00 & 0.00 & 9a  & PP & 800 & 1073 & 12.07 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
           & 0.00+0.00 & 0.00 & 7b  & PP & 828 & 1101 & 11.04 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
           & 0.00+0.00 & 0.00 & 8c  & PP & 842 & 1115 & 10.79 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
           & 0.00+0.00 & 0.00 & 5  & PP & 856 & 1129 & 10.24 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 &  41.22\\
           & 0.00+0.00 & 0.00 & 6  & PP & 870 & 1143 & 9.95 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
           & 0.00+0.00 & 0.00 & 4  & PP & 885 & 1158 & 9.50 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
           & 0.00+0.00 & 0.00 & 3b  & CC & 1538 & 1811 & 1.70 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
           & 0.00+0.00 & 0.00 & 5b  & CC & 1548 & 1821 & 1.65 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
           & 0.00+0.00 & 0.00 & 2b  & CC & 1557 & 1830 & 1.60 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
           & 0.00+0.00 & 0.00 & 1b  & CC & 1572 & 1846 & 1.53 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
           & 0.00+0.00 & 0.00 & 4b  & CC & 1588 & 1861 & 1.45 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
\midrule

Ne_{100}+2F
           & 0.93+0.10 & 3.35 & 9  & PP & 821 & 1094 & 10.21 & -4.31 & 7486.03 & 582.01 & 1024 & 39.24\\
           & 0.93+0.10 & 3.35 & 4  & PP & 849 & 1122 & 9.67 & -4.31 & 7486.03 & 582.01 & 1024 & 39.24\\
           & 0.93+0.10 & 3.35 & 17--18  & CC & 1502 & 1775 & 1.98 & -4.31 & 7486.03 & 582.01 & 1024 & 39.24\\
           & 0.93+0.10 & 3.35 & 13--14--15  & CC & 1550 & 1823 & 1.71 & -4.31 & 7486.03 & 582.01 & 1024 & 39.24\\
           & 0.93+0.10 & 3.35 & 36--38--39  & CC & 1585 & 1859 & 1.54 & -4.31 & 7486.03 & 582.01 & 1024 & 39.24\\
           & 0.93+0.10 & 3.35 & 9--10--11  & CC & 1589 & 1861 & 1.53 & -4.31 & 7486.03 & 582.01 & 1024 & 39.24\\
\midrule
Ne_{100}+4F
           & 2.42+0.07 & 8.39 & n.d.  & PP & 679 & 952 & 10.72 & -4.31 & 8395.10 & 393.24 & 908 & 28.81\\
           & 2.42+0.07 & 8.39 & n.d.  & PP & 712 & 985 &   9.87 & -4.31 & 8395.10 & 393.24 & 908 & 28.81\\
           & 2.42+0.07 & 8.39 & n.d.  & CC & 1513 & 1786 & 1.74 & -4.31 & 8395.10 & 393.24 & 908 & 28.81\\
           & 2.42+0.07 & 8.39 & n.d.  & CC & 1561 & 1834 & 1.52 & -4.31 & 8395.10 & 393.24 & 908 & 28.81\\
           & 2.42+0.07 & 8.39 & n.d.  & CC & 1585 & 1858 & 1.41 & -4.31 & 8395.10 & 393.24 & 908 & 28.81\\
           & 2.42+0.07 & 8.39 & n.d.  & CC & 1589 & 1862 & 1.39 & -4.31 & 8395.10 & 393.24 & 908 & 28.81\\
\midrule
Ne_{100}+6F
           & 3.62+0.07 & 12.03 & n.d.  & PP & 596 & 869 & 11.11 & -4.31 & 8526.37 & 324.43 & 832 & 27.57\\
           & 3.62+0.07 & 12.03 & n.d.  & PP & 622 & 895 & 10.67 & -4.31 & 8526.37 & 324.43 & 832 & 27.57\\
           & 3.62+0.07 & 12.03 &     3  & PP & 651 & 924 & 10.03 & -4.31 & 8526.37 & 324.43 & 832 & 27.57\\
           & 3.62+0.07 & 12.03 & n.d.  & PP & 660 & 933 & 9.85 & -4.31 & 8526.37 & 324.43 & 832 & 27.57\\
           & 3.62+0.07 & 12.03 & n.d.  & CC & 1514 & 1787 & 1.51 & -4.31 & 8526.37 & 324.43 & 832 & 27.57\\
           & 3.62+0.07 & 12.03 & n.d.  & CC & 1558 & 1831 & 1.32 & -4.31 & 8526.37 & 324.43 & 832 & 27.57\\
           & 3.62+0.07 & 12.03 & n.d.  & CC & 1581 & 1854 & 1.23 & -4.31 & 8526.37 & 324.43 & 832 & 27.57\\
           & 3.62+0.07 & 12.03 & n.d.  & CC & 1582 & 1855 & 1.22 & -4.31 & 8526.37 & 324.43 & 832 & 27.57\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**Example 2 – original code as MWE**

Here is you code as an MWE, unnecessary packages removed, but geometry added. As you will see, you tabular now centres between the left and right margins.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=0.625in, right=0.625in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}

%\textwidth=6.5in \textheight 9in \oddsidemargin=0in \topmargin=-0.5in

\cfoot{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\scriptsize
    \centering
    \caption{Ne-Kls Viscosity Data Ne75}
    \medskip
    \label{Ne$_{75}$Kls$_{25}$+XF Viscosity Data}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|cccccccccccc|}

        \hline
        \hline

            Sample & Wt. \% F & Mol \% F & Segment & Method & $T$ ($^{\circ}C$) & $T$ (K) & log$\eta$ & A & B & C & T$^{12}$ & m   \\
        \hline 
        \hline
     Ne$_{100}$+0F & 0.00$\pm$0.00 & 0.00 & 9a  & PP & 800 & 1073 & 12.07 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
                 & 0.00$\pm$0.00 & 0.00 & 7b  & PP & 828 & 1101 & 11.04 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
                & 0.00$\pm$0.00 & 0.00 & 8c  & PP & 842 & 1115 & 10.79 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
                 & 0.00$\pm$0.00 & 0.00 & 5  & PP & 856 & 1129 & 10.24 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 &  41.22\\
                & 0.00$\pm$0.00 & 0.00 & 6  & PP & 870 & 1143 & 9.95 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
                & 0.00$\pm$0.00 & 0.00 & 4  & PP & 885 & 1158 & 9.50 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
                 & 0.00$\pm$0.00 & 0.00 & 3b  & CC & 1538 & 1811 & 1.70 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
                & 0.00$\pm$0.00 & 0.00 & 5b  & CC & 1548 & 1821 & 1.65 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
                 & 0.00$\pm$0.00 & 0.00 & 2b  & CC & 1557 & 1830 & 1.60 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
                & 0.00$\pm$0.00 & 0.00 & 1b  & CC & 1572 & 1846 & 1.53 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
                & 0.00$\pm$0.00 & 0.00 & 4b  & CC & 1588 & 1861 & 1.45 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\

     \hline 
    Ne$_{100}$+2F & 0.93$\pm$0.10 & 3.35 & 9  & PP & 821 & 1094 & 10.21 & -4.31 & 7486.03 & 582.01 & 1024 & 39.24\\
                    & 0.93$\pm$0.10 & 3.35 & 4  & PP & 849 & 1122 & 9.67 & -4.31 & 7486.03 & 582.01 & 1024 & 39.24\\
                    & 0.93$\pm$0.10 & 3.35 & 17-18  & CC & 1502 & 1775 & 1.98 & -4.31 & 7486.03 & 582.01 & 1024 & 39.24\\
                    & 0.93$\pm$0.10 & 3.35 & 13-14-15  & CC & 1550 & 1823 & 1.71 & -4.31 & 7486.03 & 582.01 & 1024 & 39.24\\
                    & 0.93$\pm$0.10 & 3.35 & 36-38-39  & CC & 1585 & 1859 & 1.54 & -4.31 & 7486.03 & 582.01 & 1024 & 39.24\\
                    & 0.93$\pm$0.10 & 3.35 & 9-10-11  & CC & 1589 & 1861 & 1.53 & -4.31 & 7486.03 & 582.01 & 1024 & 39.24\\


     \hline
    Ne$_{100}$+4F & 2.42$\pm$0.07 & 8.39 & n.d.  & PP & 679 & 952 & 10.72 & -4.31 & 8395.10 & 393.24 & 908 & 28.81\\
                  & 2.42$\pm$0.07 & 8.39 & n.d.  & PP & 712 & 985 & 9.87 & -4.31 & 8395.10 & 393.24 & 908 & 28.81\\
                  & 2.42$\pm$0.07 & 8.39 & n.d.  & CC & 1513 & 1786 & 1.74 & -4.31 & 8395.10 & 393.24 & 908 & 28.81\\
                  & 2.42$\pm$0.07 & 8.39 & n.d.  & CC & 1561 & 1834 & 1.52 & -4.31 & 8395.10 & 393.24 & 908 & 28.81\\
                  & 2.42$\pm$0.07 & 8.39 & n.d.  & CC & 1585 & 1858 & 1.41 & -4.31 & 8395.10 & 393.24 & 908 & 28.81\\
                  & 2.42$\pm$0.07 & 8.39 & n.d.  & CC & 1589 & 1862 & 1.39 & -4.31 & 8395.10 & 393.24 & 908 & 28.81\\
     \hline
     Ne$_{100}$+6F & 3.62$\pm$0.07 & 12.03 & n.d.  & PP & 596 & 869 & 11.11 & -4.31 & 8526.37 & 324.43 & 832 & 27.57\\
                   & 3.62$\pm$0.07 & 12.03 & n.d.  & PP & 622 & 895 & 10.67 & -4.31 & 8526.37 & 324.43 & 832 & 27.57\\
                   & 3.62$\pm$0.07 & 12.03 & 3  & PP & 651 & 924 & 10.03 & -4.31 & 8526.37 & 324.43 & 832 & 27.57\\
                   & 3.62$\pm$0.07 & 12.03 & n.d.  & PP & 660 & 933 & 9.85 & -4.31 & 8526.37 & 324.43 & 832 & 27.57\\
                   & 3.62$\pm$0.07 & 12.03 & n.d.  & CC & 1514 & 1787 & 1.51 & -4.31 & 8526.37 & 324.43 & 832 & 27.57\\
                   & 3.62$\pm$0.07 & 12.03 & n.d.  & CC & 1558 & 1831 & 1.32 & -4.31 & 8526.37 & 324.43 & 832 & 27.57\\
                   & 3.62$\pm$0.07 & 12.03 & n.d.  & CC & 1581 & 1854 & 1.23 & -4.31 & 8526.37 & 324.43 & 832 & 27.57\\
                   & 3.62$\pm$0.07 & 12.03 & n.d.  & CC & 1582 & 1855 & 1.22 & -4.31 & 8526.37 & 324.43 & 832 & 27.57\\

        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

You can  obtain a table that fits between the margins reducing the value of `\tabcolsep` and writing some column heads on two lines with the `\makecell` command. Other than that, I added `siunitx` to have a nicer alignment where necessary, and a simpler typing of uncertainties in the second column.

```
    \documentclass[12pt, english]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{babel}
    \usepackage{makecell}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr,wrapfig,color,lastpage}

    \usepackage{setspace} \onehalfspacing \addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.875in}
    \addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.875in}
    \addtolength{\textwidth}{1.75in}
    \addtolength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
    \addtolength{\textheight}{1in}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
    \usepackage{enumerate}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{adjustbox}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{csvsimple}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
    \usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
    \usepackage{chemmacros}
    \usepackage[round, semicolon]{natbib}
    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}

    \chemsetup{ modules = all, formula = mhchem }

    \definecolor{Red}{rgb}{0.8,0.2,0.2} \definecolor{Blue}{rgb}{0.2,0.2,0.8}

    \sloppy \textwidth=6.5in \textheight 9in \oddsidemargin=0in \topmargin=-0.5in

    \cfoot{\thepage}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[H] \scriptsize \centering \caption{Ne-Kls Viscosity Data Ne75} \medskip \label{Ne${75}$Kls${25}$+XF Viscosity Data}
    \sisetup{table-format=4.0, table-number-alignment=center}%\begin{adjustbox}{angle=90}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|S[table-format=1.2,separate-uncertainty,table-figures-uncertainty=1] S[table-format=2.2]cc*{2}{S}S[table-format=2.2]S[table-format=-1.2]*{2}{c}S|c|}

    \hline
    \hline
    Sample & {\makecell{Wt. \\ \% F}} &{ \makecell{Mol\\ \% F}} & Segment & Method & {\makecell{$T$\\ (\si{\degreeCelsius})}} &{\makecell{$T$\\ (\si{\K})}} & {$\log\eta$} & {A} & B & C & {T$^{12}$} & m \\
    \hline
    \hline
        Ne$_{100}$+0F & 0.00(0) & 0.00 & 9a & PP & 800 & 1073 & 12.07 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
            & 0.00(0) & 0.00 & 7b & PP & 828 & 1101 & 11.04 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
            & 0.00(0) & 0.00 & 8c & PP & 842 & 1115 & 10.79 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
            & 0.00(0) & 0.00 & 5 & PP & 856 & 1129 & 10.24 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22\\
            & 0.00(0) & 0.00 & 6 & PP & 870 & 1143 & 9.95 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
            & 0.00(0) & 0.00 & 4 & PP & 885 & 1158 & 9.50 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
            & 0.00(0) & 0.00 & 3b & CC & 1538 & 1811 & 1.70 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
            & 0.00(0) & 0.00 & 5b & CC & 1548 & 1821 & 1.65 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
            & 0.00(0) & 0.00 & 2b & CC & 1557 & 1830 & 1.60 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
            & 0.00(0) & 0.00 & 1b & CC & 1572 & 1846 & 1.53 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
            & 0.00(0) & 0.00 & 4b & CC & 1588 & 1861 & 1.45 & -4.31 & 7025.89 & 646.54 & 1074 & 41.22 \\
    \hline
        Ne$_{100}$+2F & 0.93(10) & 3.35 & 9 & PP & 821 & 1094 & 10.21 & -4.31 & 7486.03 & 582.01 & 1024 & 39.24\\
            & 0.93(10) & 3.35 & 4 & PP & 849 & 1122 & 9.67 & -4.31 & 7486.03 & 582.01 & 1024 & 39.24\\
            & 0.93(10) & 3.35 & 17-18 & CC & 1502 & 1775 & 1.98 & -4.31 & 7486.03 & 582.01 & 1024 & 39.24\\
            & 0.93(10) & 3.35 & 13-14-15 & CC & 1550 & 1823 & 1.71 & -4.31 & 7486.03 & 582.01 & 1024 & 39.24\\
            & 0.93(10) & 3.35 & 36-38-39 & CC & 1585 & 1859 & 1.54 & -4.31 & 7486.03 & 582.01 & 1024 & 39.24\\
            & 0.93(10) & 3.35 & 9-10-11 & CC & 1589 & 1861 & 1.53 & -4.31 & 7486.03 & 582.01 & 1024 & 39.24\\
    \hline
        Ne$_{100}$+4F & 2.42(7) & 8.39 & n.d. & PP & 679 & 952 & 10.72 & -4.31 & 8395.10 & 393.24 & 908 & 28.81\\
              & 2.42(7) & 8.39 & n.d. & PP & 712 & 985 & 9.87 & -4.31 & 8395.10 & 393.24 & 908 & 28.81\\
              & 2.42(7) & 8.39 & n.d. & CC & 1513 & 1786 & 1.74 & -4.31 & 8395.10 & 393.24 & 908 & 28.81\\
              & 2.42(7) & 8.39 & n.d. & CC & 1561 & 1834 & 1.52 & -4.31 & 8395.10 & 393.24 & 908 & 28.81\\
              & 2.42(7) & 8.39 & n.d. & CC & 1585 & 1858 & 1.41 & -4.31 & 8395.10 & 393.24 & 908 & 28.81\\
              & 2.42(7) & 8.39 & n.d. & CC & 1589 & 1862 & 1.39 & -4.31 & 8395.10 & 393.24 & 908 & 28.81\\
    \hline
        Ne$_{100}$+6F & 3.62(7) & 12.03 & n.d. & PP & 596 & 869 & 11.11 & -4.31 & 8526.37 & 324.43 & 832 & 27.57\\
               & 3.62(7) & 12.03 & n.d. & PP & 622 & 895 & 10.67 & -4.31 & 8526.37 & 324.43 & 832 & 27.57\\
               & 3.62(7) & 12.03 & 3 & PP & 651 & 924 & 10.03 & -4.31 & 8526.37 & 324.43 & 832 & 27.57\\
               & 3.62(7) & 12.03 & n.d. & PP & 660 & 933 & 9.85 & -4.31 & 8526.37 & 324.43 & 832 & 27.57\\
               & 3.62(7) & 12.03 & n.d. & CC & 1514 & 1787 & 1.51 & -4.31 & 8526.37 & 324.43 & 832 & 27.57\\
               & 3.62(7) & 12.03 & n.d. & CC & 1558 & 1831 & 1.32 & -4.31 & 8526.37 & 324.43 & 832 & 27.57\\
               & 3.62(7) & 12.03 & n.d. & CC & 1581 & 1854 & 1.23 & -4.31 & 8526.37 & 324.43 & 832 & 27.57\\
               & 3.62(7) & 12.03 & n.d. & CC & 1582 & 1855 & 1.22 & -4.31 & 8526.37 & 324.43 & 832 & 27.57\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]